# "It is required for ... to be ..."

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it grammatically correct to write:

"Condition A is **required for** P **to be** a probability measure"?

I don't see any mistake, but I'm not completely sure about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the sentence, unless the meaning is different from what you intended. As the sentence is written, P needs A to be a probability measure, but it *may or may not* need other things as well (Conditions B, C, etc.).

Other ways to express the same idea:

> Condition A is necessary for P to be a probability measure

> P cannot be a probability measure unless it satisfies Condition A.

> To be a probability measure, P requi

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the extra logical equivalences.